# Specific user groups can see specific parts of content + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, permissions, roles

I have 2 types of users:

1. free
2. paid

I have a table **jeweller** with `id, name, description, type, ...` . 
I also have a table **users** with `id,name,email, type and password`. The type in my users table is to mark the free or paid users.

Now I would like to know how can I make sure that for example the

1. free users can only see name and type from the jeweller table
2. paid users can see all the fields of the jeweller

How can I arrange this in my mysql database and in PHP?

Comment: You could handle this in the application layer.

Answer (score 1):

Make a user table with a privilege column. Save different value for this 2types.  A boolean data for privilage will work for you. With different privilege level fetch different data.

Answer (score 0):

Store the user's `type` in your `$_SESSION` and then use a simple if statement:

```
echo $jewelername;
echo $jewelertype;

if($_SESSION["user_type"]=="paid"){
    echo $jewelerdescription;
    echo $jewelerotherfield;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a table `privileges` formed by two columns. Example `id_privilege` and `name_privilege`.
Than create another table `user_privileges` with other two columns, `id_privilege` and `id_user`.
Now insert the id of the user and id of privilege in the table `user_privileges`and in PHP check if user have one or another privileges.

```
/*
 Read From database
 */
if($array["name_privilege"]=="paid"){
    // show something
}
```